# Joining list with comma

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i want to join my list with comma to separate each itemlist from a class but it just can't giving me access to that class property 
(i'm sorry i'm not good at explaning this, but i hope with this code sample you will understand)

```
public class CategoryDetail
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectDetail
{
    public List<CategoryDetail> categories { get; set; }

    public string categoryList
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join<CategoryDetail>(",", categories.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

so this is my code that i use for retrieving data from json, and what i want is that in my xaml i will bind it into categoryList and it will showing categoryDetail title property that separated by comma

Comment: For display you should return `categories` as an `ObservableList` and bind the properties you want to show to the controls there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify generic parameter type - it can be inferred from usage. Also you need to project categories to sequence of titles:

```
public string categoryList
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(",", categories.Select(c => c.title));
    }
}
```